# Inconsistent Expression Language behaviour, same expression different values

Tags: java, jsp, el

The same EL expression `${taskId}` gives two different values in different places.

I am using the Stripes framework, along with MongoDB and Morphia for Object-Mapping (and of course Java/JSP/etc).

Using the following JSP/Expression Language code:

```
<c:forEach items="${actionBean.tasks}" var="listTask">
<c:set var="taskId" scope="page" value="${listTask.id}"/>
<s:form method="post" beanclass="action.TaskActionBean">
    ${taskId}<s:hidden name="task.id" value="${taskId}"/>
    <s:submit name="promoteTask" value="Up" />
</s:form>
</c:forEach>
```

Gives the following generated code:

```
<form method="post" action="/scrumyogi/"> 
    4ef99b730364de7ec70dbd68
  <input type="hidden" value="4ef99b6c0364de7ec70dbd67" name="task.id">
  <input type="submit" value="Up" name="promoteTask">
    <div style="display: none;">
      <input type="hidden" value="NPNEJw6tUWfRBXf-vVOLTw==" name="_sourcePage">
      <input type="hidden" value="XbfUDiSHGrU=" name="__fp">
    </div>
</form>
```

As you can see ${taskId} is printing out `4ef99b730364de7ec70dbd68` and then `4ef99b6c0364de7ec70dbd67`, which makes no sense to me, I need ${taskId} to print out the same value `4ef99b730364de7ec70dbd68` is the correct one.

Is there some known issue that could cause this.

EDIT: the real problem is that the ${taskId} within the hidden form tag is incorrect, I printed the other value to see what the expression contains, and then found that it's different in the different locations - which make things seriously confusing.

ActionBean code:

```
@UrlBinding("/")
public class TaskActionBean extends BaseActionBean{

    String taskId;
    Task task = new Task();
    List<Task> tasks;

    public final static String DISPLAY = "/index.jsp";

    @DefaultHandler
    public Resolution listTasks(){
        tasks = Dao.datastore().find(Task.class).order("rank").asList();
        return new ForwardResolution(DISPLAY);
    }


    public Resolution promoteTask(){

        task.promoteTask();     
        tasks = Dao.datastore().find(Task.class).order("rank").asList();

        return new ForwardResolution(DISPLAY);
    }



    // ... getters and setters
```

Comment: The code is snippetised, I don't think the other code is relevant but I can include more if this is not enough.

Comment: For the time being I've solved this by using a <s:link> object, however I'd still be keen to understand what's going on here, if anyone knows.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `taskId` field in you action bean, and according to [stripes taglib documentation](http://stripes.sourceforge.net/docs/current/taglib/):

> The hidden tag assigns the value attribute by scanning in the following order:
>
> 1. for one or more values with the same name in the HttpServletRequest
> 2. for a field on the ActionBean with the same name (if a bean instance is present)
> 3. by collapsing the body content to a String, if a body is present
> 4. referring to the result of the EL expression contained in the value attribute of the tag.

So it probably finds the field in your action bean and takes the value from there.

The other (jsp el) `${taskId}` is assigned from task list element.

Change the `taskId` to some name that doesn't coincide with your action bean field and it should work.